# Moving to on-prem self-hosted Linux agent causes container jobs to fail

Tags: azure-devops, containers

I was able to get my pipeline container jobs working up to a point using Azure hosted Agent pool, but now need to shift to using an on-premise agent running RHEL8.

This has caused my pipeline to fail due to the container not running when it attempts to run an exec command against it. I am using the same image and same pipeline settings, the only thing that has changed is the Agent Pool.

In the pipeline details I can see it create a docker network, and then create a container from the image. Then it starts the container but it moves to exited state and then causes later command to fail.

Here is the pipeline log:

```
/usr/bin/docker info -f "{{range .Plugins.Network}}{{println .}}{{end}}"
bridge
macvlan
ipvlan

/usr/bin/docker network create --label 45fb3a vsts_network_4963fe13917e4bea8148946b9b98de8c
vsts_network_4963fe13917e4bea8148946b9b98de8c

/usr/bin/docker inspect --format="{{index .Config.Labels \"com.azure.dev.pipelines.agent.handler.node.path\"}}" ***/myocr/myimage:prod
/usr/bin/docker create --name myimage_b66838 --label 45fb3a --network vsts_network_4963fe13917e4bea8148946b9b98de8c  -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/service_account/ado_agent_myProject/_work/1":"/__w/1" -v "/home/service_account/ado_agent_myProject/_work/_temp":"/__w/_temp" -v "/home/service_account/ado_agent_myProject/_work/_tasks":"/__w/_tasks" -v "/home/service_account/ado_agent_myProject/_work/_tool":"/__t" -v "/home/service_account/ado_agent_myProject/externals":"/__a/externals":ro -v "/home/service_account/ado_agent_myProject/_work/.taskkey":"/__w/.taskkey" ***/myProject/myimage:prod "/__a/externals/node/bin/node" -e "setInterval(function(){}, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);"
f09eb901eaabaae154bd7083ac8c8a39b54666b4cf9401e6de1d4bf1cc8ab951
DockerActionRetries variable value: True

/usr/bin/docker start f09eb901eaabaae154bd7083ac8c8a39b54666b4cf9401e6de1d4bf1cc8ab951
f09eb901eaabaae154bd7083ac8c8a39b54666b4cf9401e6de1d4bf1cc8ab951

/usr/bin/docker ps --all --filter id=f09eb901eaabaae154bd7083ac8c8a39b54666b4cf9401e6de1d4bf1cc8ab951 --filter status=running --no-trunc --format "{{.ID}} {{.Status}}"
/usr/bin/docker ps --all --filter id=f09eb901eaabaae154bd7083ac8c8a39b54666b4cf9401e6de1d4bf1cc8ab951 --no-trunc --format "{{.ID}} {{.Status}}"
f09eb901eaabaae154bd7083ac8c8a39b54666b4cf9401e6de1d4bf1cc8ab951 Exited (139) Less than a second ago

/usr/bin/docker logs --details f09eb901eaabaae154bd7083ac8c8a39b54666b4cf9401e6de1d4bf1cc8ab951
##[warning]Docker container f09eb901eaabaae154bd7083ac8c8a39b54666b4cf9401e6de1d4bf1cc8ab951 is not in running state.
```

Looking through that create command it looks like it's expecting the mounted command `"/__a/externals/node/bin/node"` to keep the container in a running state.

Can someone provide some advice on how to diagnose this further, or maybe adjust settings on my RHEL8 container host to make this simpler? Since it worked fine on Azure hosted I am thinking its just a config/expectation issue.

Comment: My problem is that I was running podman and podman-docker on my agent and it not supported by ADO. I had to completely remove podman and install docker natively using the CentOS RPMs and then my container jobs ran.